# No armature deform option?

Tags: armature, surface-deform

I'm trying to import the model by the tutorial, and I don't have this option. What's the deal?

[image]

Comment: i don't see that you have selected any armature? you have to first select your object, then shift-select your armature, then ctrl-p

Answer (score 0):

Parenting works to parent all selected non-active objects to the active one, and as Chris said, the armature is not active or even selected. Select it last (you can do this by holding [either Shift or Ctrl?] and clicking the armature in the Outliner, or you can just hold Shift and select it in the 3D Viewport), and then press Ctrl+P.